# How can I group children and parents in a single query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sorting, grouping

I have a table that represents a simple parent->child hierarchy, something like:

```
             Table "public.transactions"
   Column  | Type          |  Modifiers
-----------+---------------+-----------------------------------------------------------
 id        | integer       | not null default nextval('transactions_id_seq'::regclass)
 parent_id | integer       | not null default 0
 amount    | numeric(15,4) | not null default 0.0000
```

I'd like to display the table with child transactions (those with a parent_id > 0) grouped below their respective parents. e.g.,

```
parent
   child
   child
parent
   child
parent
parent
```

*(note: nested spaces are only here to visually represent hierarchy, they're not needed for the query results)*

Can I do this in a single query? I'm running Postgresql 9.3 in case it matters.

Comment: Such questions should provide sample data, ideally an SQLfiddle. Also: what have you tried?

Comment: All SQL engines work with relations, which can be thought of as tabular structures. The nested view that you gave is not tabular, so a query can't return anything that looks like that. You _can_ return something like `parent1 child1 \n parent1 child2 \n parent2 child1 ...`

Comment: @voithos The nesting is there just to visually represent the hierarchy, it won't be needed as part of the query.

Comment: How many levels of nesting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a *single level of nesting*, this may seem almost trivial:

```
SELECT *
FROM   transactions
ORDER  BY COALESCE(parent_id, id), id
```

Comment: This is not group....this is order...try to order them by name (parent by name and the same time by name - children)